# Foreign key and registration form

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli, foreign-keys

I really need help on this and couldn't find any previous questions related to my problem so here I am.

I have a registration form which is split up into 3 stages and therefore 3 tables. Keep in mind I have indexed and created foreign key constraints in phpmyadmin.

First stage is users (table):

```
CREATE TABLE `dbtest`.`users`(
`user_id` INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`email` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE(`email`)
 ) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

When a user fills in the first stage and the data is posted into the database and first user_id becomes 1. The user is then redirected onto the next stage (table):

```
CREATE TABLE `dbtest`.`personal`(
`player_id` INT(5) NOT NULL,
`first` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
`last` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
`mobile` INT(12) NOT NULL,
`parentmobile` INT(12) NOT NULL,
`gender` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
`address` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`city` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`postcode` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`county` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
`country` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(mobile)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

When he fills in this form all the data gets posted into the database however player_id is 0 not 1. My question is how do I pass the user_id from stage 1 to player_id in stage 2. I have attached pictures my code.

PHP code for Stage 1:

[image]

PHP code for Stage 2:

[image]

Comment: Very bad approach. What will happen if the user never fills other stages, but only the first one? you will have partial data in your database. Better do it with hidden DIV tabs (i.e. switch between them using JS) and submit all the data at once.

Comment: Don't design your database based on your UI. They are two very different things. A page (or a form) <> a table in the database. Gather all of your data as @mitkosoft suggests, then submit it all at once. If you need to allow for partial completions of the form then you can put it into the table and get back the ID value to then update on subsequent forms, but it shouldn't necessarily be one table to one form.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know php, but I have faced similar problems in other languages. What you want, is the id of the last inserted row, right? And then use it to insert the other related parts of the registration.

All you really need to know, is how to find the id:

**Object oriented style**

```
mixed $mysqli->insert_id;
```

**Procedural style**

```
mixed mysqli_insert_id ( mysqli $link )
```

Reference and more info: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php